# Shape mismatch when trying to reclassify

Tags: python, numpy

I have a raster that what to conduct the following condition:

```
if pixel value <25 then pixelvalue*1.6 and if pixel value>=25 then (pixelvalue*0.9)+16.67
```

and I wrote this code but I get an error

```
import rasterio as rio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy

Ic=rio.open("/Users/pegah/Desktop/Climare_final_DATA/Cli_Index.tif").read(1)

A=1.6*Ic
B=16.67+(0.9*Ic)

Ic_reclass = copy.copy(Ic)
Ic_reclass[np.where(Ic<25)] = A
Ic_reclass[np.where(Ic>=25)] = B 

def rio_arr_to_raster(dataarray, input_value_raster_path, out_raster):
    src = rio.open(input_value_raster_path)
    # context manager.
    with rio.drivers():
        profile = src.profile
        profile.update(
            dtype=rio.float32,
            count=1,
            compress='lzw')
        with rio.open(out_raster, 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(dataarray.astype(rio.float32), 1)

rio_arr_to_raster(Ic_reclass,"/Users/pegah/Desktop/Climare_final_DATA/Cli_Index.tif","/Users/pegah/Desktop/Climare_final_DATA/Corre_Cli_Index.tif")
```

The error is:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (184,460) could not
>   be broadcast to indexing result of shape (70947,)

Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: What line number is the error on?  Please always include the full error message that results from running any code that you present.

Comment: The Python traceback tells us which line of your script contains the problem. Without it, we can only guess. The traceback begins with `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: so sorry for inconvenient, here is the whole error .ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cf8663ea66f8> in <module>()
     10 
     11 Ic_reclass = copy.copy(Ic)
---> 12 Ic_reclass[np.where(Ic<25)] = A
     13 Ic_reclass[np.where(Ic>=25)] = B
     14 

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (184,460) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (70947,)

Comment: I still had a hard time understand that traceback. It would be better if it was formatted as you see it in the terminal, but I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is either at line 12 or 13 and is specifically that the shapes of the arrays on the left and right hand sides of your assignment do not match. `Ic_reclass[np.where(Ic < 25)]` is a 1-D array and `A` and `B` are 2-D arrays of different sizes.

It looks to me that what you intend is

```
Ic_reclass = np.where(Ic < 25, A, B)
```

In other words, create a new array taking from either `A` or `B` depending on the condition `Ic < 25`.

By the way, http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting is a great lecture on how numpy broadcasting works.

Comment: thank you so much, this time I was able to write array in the same shape, but when I checked it in Qgis I realized that all the values got nan.

Comment: Please mark this question answered. If you've got any more questions about rasterio usage, I think it would best to start a new question.